# Is semi-simple Lie algebra $L$, satisfy $ L\in{\rm Max}-\triangleleft$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

A Lie algebra $L$ satisfy the maximum condition for ideals, if for each , ascending chain $H_{1} \subseteq H_{2} \subseteq \ldots $ an index $m$ exists such that $H_{i}=H_{k}$ if $m<i$, $m<k .$

We say in short: $ L\in{\rm Max}-\triangleleft$.

Is every semi-simple Lie algebra $L$, satisfy $ L\in{\rm Max}-\triangleleft$?

If its true, how can i prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Can a semisimple Lie algebra have infinitely many ideals?

Comment: Would the person who voted to delete this answer care to explain?

Comment: Using Proposition 7.22 in (https://math.msu.edu/user_content/docs/Semisimple%20Complex%20Lie%20Algebras%20-%20Thesis20170110151728764.pdf) semisimple Lie algebra may have infinitely many ideals

Comment: Is this true or what?

Comment: The Lie algebra in that proposition is not semisimple because a one-dimensional Lie algebra is not semisimple.

Comment: It seems from your answer and comments that semi-simple Lie algebra can't have infinitely many ideals. Is this true ?

Comment: If you cannot figure that out yourself, honestly I think you will not get far without re-learning the basics of the theory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110918/discussion-between-hamada-al-and-torsten-schoeneberg).

Comment: I understand from your answer on a similar question that every finite-dimensional semi-simple Lie algebra $L$, satisfy $ L\in{\rm Max}-\triangleleft$.
But it seems that inifinite-dimensional semi-simple Lie algebra $L$, doesn't satisfy $ L\in{\rm Max}-\triangleleft$.

Comment: I assumed for this post that semisimple means finite-dimensional. An arbitrary direct sum of simple Lie algebras does not necessarily satisfy that Max property.